# Esconder uma div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tenho duas divs e quero que uma desapareça quando chegar no 'md' a outra ocupe as 12 colunas. Como posso fazer isso com Bootstrap?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    Essa desaparece quando chegar em md
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Essa ocupa todas as 12 colunas quando chegar em md
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como que você está fazendo para "chegar no md"?? Edite a tua pergunta pois ela não está clara.

Comment: Estou usando Bootstrap

Comment: Quem controla isso é o JS, não o Bootstrap.

Comment: A que desaparece ao chegar em **md** deve ocupar quanto antes de desaparecer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap possui uma classe `display` abreviada como **"d-{breakpoint}-{value}"** você pode usá-la para delimitar break-points.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 d-md-none">
    Essa desaparece quando chegar em md
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 d-none d-md-block">
    Essa ocupa todas as 12 colunas quando chegar em md
  </div>
</div>
```

Neste exemplo basta clicar em executar e depois click em "Página toda" para ver a primeira `<div>` desaparecer.

---

Referencia : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando Flexbox (bootstrap), atribua um ID para a div que irá desaparecer e atribua a classe col-12 (para resoluções mobile) e col-md-6 (para resoluções maiores que média) para a div que deve ocupar as 12 colunas, e col-6 para a div que deve desaparecer.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="identificadorDaDiv" class="col-6">
    Essa desaparece quando chegar em md
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
    Essa ocupa todas as 12 colunas quando chegar em md
  </div>
</div>
```

No seu CSS, você pode adicionar um @media query para resoluções medium ou menores (O padrão do bootstrap é 768px)

```
@media screen and (max-resolution: 767px) {
    #identificadorDaDiv {
        display: hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como são 2 `divs`, coloque `col-6` em cada dentro de um `row`.

A classe `d-md-none` irá esconder a `div` ao entrar no **md**, e a classe `col-md-12` irá ocupar as 12 colunas ao entrar no **md**.

**Exemplo:**

```css
div.container div.col-6:nth-child(1){
   background: yellow;
}
div.container div.col-6:nth-child(2){
   background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 d-md-none">
       Essa desaparece quando chegar em md
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
       Essa ocupa todas as 12 colunas quando chegar em md
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```